# org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt

My application is based on GWT,java,hibernate

I have class Like

```
 public class Test implements Serializable {
     private long id;
     private String companyName;

     public long getId() {
          return id;
     }
     public void setId(long id) {
         this.id = id;
     }
     public String getCompanyName() {
         return companyName;
     }
     public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
         this.companyName = companyName;
     }
 }
```

Below is my hbm file

Test.hbm.xml:

```
  <property name="id" column="id" type="long"/>
  <property name="companyName" column="company_name" type="string"/>
```

When i tried to debug my application it will throws below error.

```
org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for companyName in class Test
at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.createGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:282)
at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.getGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:275)
at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getGetter(Property.java:272)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildPropertyGetter(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:247)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:125)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:55)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:56)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:295)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:434)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:109)
at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:55)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:226)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1294)
```

Its worked fine in one aaplication and gives error in other application.

Can anybody help to resolved this exception?

Comment: You're going to need to show us all of your Hibernate files.  Also include your schema if it looks suspicious.

Comment: Can you take a look into the `.class` file that is being deployed? Check if indeed does have getters and setters.

Comment: I created war and deploy it,its working fine.but in eclipse still its throw error.i have check class file and its updated its contains getter and setter method.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to clean your project, rebuild and redeploy it. Maybe some changes were not taken into account.

Comment: i have clean and rebuilt it but still same problem.